# Multiply Eigen::Matrices without transposing first

Tags: eigen, eigen3

Say you have `Matrix<int, 4, 2>` and `Matrix<int, 3, 2>` which you want to multiply in the natural way that consumes the `-1` dimension without first transposing.

Is this possible? Or do we have to transpose first. Which would be silly (unperformative) from a cache perspective, because now the elements we are multiplying and summing aren't contiguous.

Here's a playground. https://godbolt.org/z/Gdj3sfzcb

[Pytorch provides](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.inner.html) `torch.inner` and `torch.tensordot` which do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in Numpy, `transpose()` just creates a "view". It doesn't do any expensive memory operations (unless you assign it to a new matrix). Just call `a * b.transpose()` and let Eigen handle the details of the memory access. A properly optimized BLAS library like Eigen handles the transposition on smaller tiles in temporary memory for optimal performance.

Memory order still matters for fine tuning though. If you can, write your matrix multiplications in the form `a.transpose() * b` for column-major matrices (like Eigen, Matlab), or `a * b.transpose()` for row-major matrices like those in Numpy. That saves the BLAS library the trouble of doing that transposition.

Side note: You used `auto` for your result. Please read the [Common Pitfalls](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) chapter in the documentation. Your code didn't compute a matrix multiplication, it stored an expression of one.

Comment: Thanks this saved me a lot of time. So are you saving `(a * b.transpose()).transpose();` is just as performant as `b * a.transpose();`

Comment: @TomHuntington That would be a more complicated case. The ```(a * b.transpose())``` is fine because Eigen handles all common combinations of matrix multiplications with transpositions. But transposing the output of that multiplication will probably degrade the performance of anything you do with that result (such as assigning to a matrix)

Comment: @TomHuntington A transposed view doesn't copy the entire matrix. It still causes a suboptimal memory access pattern. Matrix multiplications are an exception because they are specifically handled